# Border around screen and not frame?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently making a game in Swift/SpriteKit and I'm having a problem. Whenever I make the border for my game, the border is always around the iPhone/iPad FRAME and not the screen. So when my ball bounces it goes off of the screen and bounces off the "iPhone FRAME" and not the "scene/frame."

Can someone help me make it so my border is around the SCENE and not the FRAME?

Here is my code:

```
let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)

borderBody.friction = 0

self.physicsBody = borderBody
```

Comment: Do you mind taking a picture with the physics showing to demonstrate what you mean? You are using self.frame which should return the scene's frame, so in that case going around the scene, and going around the frame would be the same thing...

Comment: Like the frame is bigger than the scene though. The ball doesnt bounce off the edge of the screen it goes further back

Comment: Sounds like the issue might be when you initialize the scene. Maybe it is the wrong size.

Comment: In short, try to initialize the scene with skView.bounds.size and keep in mind that sometimes final size of the view may not be know in viewDidLoad method. You can use viewWillLayoutSubviews instead. Search SO about this. Also, view can have a wrong size sometimes if launch images are not set correctly, but I doubt that this have some relations with your current problem.

Comment: Whenever I try to initialize the scene there is no initializer named size

Comment: @JoshSchlabach I was meant to say, to set scene's size after you create the scene. You don't need a new initializer, you just have to set the scene's size appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I was meant to say (in comments) that you should set the scene's size to match the view's size, like this:  In the GameViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            scene.size = skView.bounds.size

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

Note the `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` which sets the scene's size to a size of the view.